# SQL RIGHT JOIN misunderstanding

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on ASP.NET application whose SQL backend (MySQL 5.6) has 4 tables:
The first table is defined in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descr` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `modus` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
);
```

These are the items managed in the application.

the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
);
```

these are files that are required for items management. Each 'item' can have 0 or multiple files ('id_item' field is filled with a valid 'id' of 'items' table).

the third table:

```
CREATE TABLE `file_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
);
```

this table describe the type of the file.

the fourth table:

```
CREATE TABLE `checklist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_type` int(11)  NOT NULL,
  `modus` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
);
```

this table, as suggested by its name, is a checklist. It describe what types of files needs to be collected for a particular 'modus', 'modus' field holds the same values as for 'modus' in 'items' table, 'id_type' holds valid 'id' values from 'file_types' table.

Let's suppose that the first table holds those items:

```
id  descr      modus
--------------------
1   First      M
2   Second     P
3   Third      M
4   Fourth     M
--------------------
```

The second:

```
id  file_path       id_item    id_type
--------------------------------------
1   file1.jpg       1          1
2   file2.jpg       1          2
3   file3.jpg       2          1
4   file4.jpg       1          4
5   file5.jpg       1          1
--------------------------------------
```

The third:

```
id  file_type
--------------
1   red
2   blue
3   green
4   default
--------------
```

The fourth table:

```
id  id_type    modus
--------------------
1   1          M
2   2          M
3   3          M
4   4          M
5   1          P
6   4          P
--------------------
```

What I need to obtain is a table with such items (referred to id_item = 1):

```
id_item  file_path       id_type   file_type
--------------------------------------------
1        file1.jpg       1         red
1        file5.jpg       1         red
1        file2.jpg       2         blue
1        file4.jpg       4         default
<null>   <null>          3         green
--------------------------------------------
```

While the result table for id_item = 2 should be the following:

```
id_item  file_path       id_type   file_type
--------------------------------------------
2        file3.jpg       1         red
<null>   <null>          4         default
--------------------------------------------
```

where of course 'id_item' is the 'id' of 'items' table, 'id_type' is the 'id' of the 'types' table etc.

In short I need to have a table that depicts the checklist status for a particularm 'item' id i.e. which files have been collected but also which of them are missing.

I tried to use RIGHT JOIN clause without success:

```
SELECT 
    items.id AS id_item,
    files.file_path AS file_path,
    file_types.id AS id_type,
    file_types.file_type AS file_type
FROM
    files
        RIGHT JOIN
    checklist ON (files.id_type = checklist.id_type )
        INNER JOIN
    items ON (files.id_item = items.id)
        AND (items.modus = checklist.modus)
        INNER JOIN
    file_types ON (checklist.id_type = file_types.id)
WHERE (items.id = 1);
```

the result of this query is:

```
 id_item   file_path    id_type    file_type
 ------------------------------------------
 1         file1.jpg    1          red
 1         file5.jpg    1          red
 1         file2.jpg    2          blue
 1         file4.jpg    4          default
```

it lacks of the last row (the missing file from the checklist).

Comment: Show your query please

Comment: how it is to possible `4 id_type` when in type table this is not exist ?

Comment: typo ... thnx. Is correct now.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam . here it is

Comment: sorry there's was another typo in result table.. just fixed it

Comment: `id_type` 4 corresponds to `green` ? . can you check third table data.

Comment: @minatverma as you can see I reindexed everything, hope now it's cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query gives you status of each item as following (kind of checklist). I had to change some of the column names which were reserved words in my test environment.

```
select item_id,
       fp filepath,
       m_type,
       item_desc,
       modee,
       (select t.type from typess t where t.id = m_type)
  from (select null      item_id,
               i.descr   item_desc,
               c.modee   modee,
               c.id_type m_type,
               null      fp
          from items i, checklist c
         where c.modee = i.modee
           and i.id = 0
           and c.id_type not in
               (select f.id_type from files f where f.id_item = i.id)
        union all
        select i.id        item_id,
               i.descr     item_desc,
               c.modee     modee,
               c.id_type   m_type,
               f.file_path fp
          from items i, checklist c, files f
         where c.modee = i.modee
           and i.id = 0
           and f.id_item = i.id
           and f.id_type = c.id_type)
 order by item_id asc, m_type asc
```

Comment: it's not working properly. Please see my last sample to the original question.

Comment: @fathim... I REALLY need to add to the result table the `files.id` field... is it possible?

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible. Add [f.id as fileid] to second inner select statement, add [null as fileid] to first inner select of union.. also add [fileid ] to top select statement.

Comment: I found the solution.. just need to add `NULL file_id` in the negative UNION statement and  `f.id file_id` in the positive one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    files.file_path,
    types.type
FROM files 
LEFT JOIN checklist ON (files.id_type = checklist.id_type )
LEFT JOIN items ON (files.id_item = items.id)
                AND (items.mode = checklist.mode)
LEFT JOIN types ON (checklist.id_type = types .id)
WHERE (items.id = 0);
```

Comment: same result as mine.

Answer (score 1):

I have created and populated your tables, but I a discrepancy between what you request (for each `item`) and your example output (for each item `type`). However, I have created a query based on the output:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT i.id, f.file_path, f.id_type 
    from checklist ck
        JOIN files f on f.id_type = ck.id_type
        JOIN items i on i.id = f.id_item AND i.mode = ck.mode AND i.id = 0
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.file_path, T.id, T.[type]
FROM types T
    LEFT JOIN cte on cte.id_type = T.id
```

**[edit]**

```
My result is the following (SQL):

id  file_path   id  type
---------------------------------
0   file1.jpg   0   red
0   file5.jpg   0   red
0   file2.jpg   1   blue
NULL    NULL    2   green
0   file4.jpg   3   default
```

**No CTE version:**

```
SELECT cte.id, cte.file_path, T.id, T.[type]
FROM types T
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT i.id, f.file_path, f.id_type 
        from checklist ck
            JOIN files f on f.id_type = ck.id_type
            JOIN items i on i.id = f.id_item AND i.mode = ck.mode AND i.id = 0
    ) cte on cte.id_type = T.id
```

Comment: I tried your code but with MySQL I cannot use such syntax 'as is' I created a view (that works as 'cte' in your code). The result didn't match anyway.

Comment: I have posted no CTE version. However, if you obtain no results with this version also, it means that I have messed something in the input data.